# How would I flatten and overlay multiple directories into one directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, directory

I want to take a list of directory hierarchies and flatten them into a single directory.  Any duplicate file later in the list will replace an earlier file.  For example...

```
foo/This/That.pm
bar/This/That.pm
bar/Some/Module.pm
wiff/This/That.pm
wiff/A/Thing/Here.pm
```

This would wind up with

```
This/That.pm      # from wiff/
Some/Module.pm    # from bar/
A/Thing/Here.pm   # from wiff/
```

I have a probably over complicated Perl program to do this.  I'm interested in the clever ways SO users might solve it.  The big hurdle is "create the intermediate directories if necessary" perhaps with some combination of basename and dirname.

The real problem I'm solving is checking the difference between two installed Perl libraries.  I'm first flattening the multiple library directories for each Perl into a single directory, simulating how Perl would search for a module.  I can then `diff -r` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind the final order of the entries, I guess this can do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A directory;

while read line; do
    directory["${line#*/}"]=${line%%/*}
done < $1

for entry in ${!directory[@]}; do
    printf "%s\t# from %s/\n" $entry ${directory[$entry]}
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh files.txt
A/Thing/Here.pm # from wiff/
This/That.pm    # from wiff/
Some/Module.pm  # from bar/
```

And if you need to move the files, then you can simply replace the printing step with a `mv` -- or `cp` --, like this:

```
for entry in ${!directory[@]}; do
    mv "${directory[$entry]}/$entry" "your_dir_path/$entry"
done
```

Comment: The ordering of the directories matters only so that the layering comes out correctly.  The final ordering of the result doesn't matter.  I've never seen `declare` and had no idea bash has hashes!  I presume files.txt is a `find . -type f` of the directories in question?

Comment: I guess you can do exactly a `find . -type f`; if you want to execute it directly, you can create a temporary file by doing: `while ...; do ..; done <(find . -type f)`